# CakePHP - Saving One to Many data to database

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm having a problem saving the data to the database. I can't seem to figure how one-to-many works. So heres the scenario: One journal voucher has many entries in it (debits and credits).

### Vouchers Table

### | voucher_id(pk) | voucherNo | notes | amount | date |

### Entries Table

### | entry_id(pk) | voucher_id(fk) accountname | description | debit | credit |

EntriesTable
`$this->belongsTo('Vouchers', [
    'foreignKey' => 'voucher_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);`

Answer (score 0):

From the vouchers's side you should be fine as described in the cookbook:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations

From the entries side is not the normal way, but you can do it also:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongsto-associations